# customizing the share extension design in swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I want to customize the design for share extension in swift 2. how can I do the customizations

```
class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController,NetworkSelectionViewControllerDelegate, PublishSelectionViewControllerDelegate{

    var selectedNetworkName = "Default"
    var selectedPublishName = "Select"

    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom Share Extension based on UIViewController:

> Use the Xcode Share Template
>
> The Xcode Share template provides default header and implementation
>   files for the principal view controller class (called
>   SharingViewController), an Info.plist file, and an interface file
>   (that is, a storyboard or xib file).
>
> NOTE:
>   To provide a custom compose view instead of the standard one, deselect
>   “Use standard social compose interface” in the Xcode target-adding
>   pane. When this checkbox is deselected, the default
>   SharingViewController class is based on NSViewController or
>   UIViewController, depending on the platform you chose.